# JavaScript HTTP Trigger Azure fuction

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create a new Azure function (HTTP Trigger) There used to be an option to choose language but now it seems to default to C# and I'f like to create a JavaScript function.

I tried deleting the C# files and replacing them with JavaScript but that then gives me a 404 when I try to run. Any idea how I can create a JavaScript function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only select the runtime stack (.NET, JS, Python, etc.) on Function creation these days. So if you selected .NET before, you will need to recreate your Function resource from scratch and select JS.